# Any way to know if an HTTP status code is from apache or PHP

Tags: php, apache, http, header, response

is there any way to know if the status code in a response header was generated by Apache itself, or if it was directed by a PHP script?

Comment: what's the difference between the two? just send a custom header in your php script (something like `X-GENERATED-WITH-PHP`), and check that.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are inspecting traffic on the client side with no real access to the server besides HTTP(S). Your best bet is indeed to check for the presence of the non-standard [`X-Powered-By`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Powered-By) header and see if its value starts with `PHP/`. However, this is only an indicator the status code in question *may* have been generated by PHP; it is not a guarantee. In fact, this header may have been forged in multiple ways. So in summary: there is no way to be sure.